# Cypress - how to wait for second of two elements to appear?

Tags: javascript, cypress

I want to wait until the second of two elements to appear before performing an action on it. Currently, I have this:

```js
    cy.get('[data-test="insert-item"]').click();
    cy.get('[data-test="textarea"]').eq(1).type('Hello').type('{enter}');
```

This currently fails. I'm assuming this is because Cypress is going to collect all the occurrences of `textarea`, then try to select the second one before it has actually rendered on the page (because of the async request that creates it). If I add `cy.wait(2000);` in between these two lines it passes.

Is there any way to do this without using `cy.wait(2000)`, so that it specifically waits until the second item has appeared?

Comment: One way would be to wait till the XHR request associated is executed by using `cy.route()`, something like `cy.server() cy.route('**/posts/**').as('getSomething') cy.wait('@getSomething')`. You can find more info on the same here - docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#Syntax

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this is just waiting for the XHR response, not the appearance of the second element.

Comment: May be you can try either one of them for the appearance of the second element and see if it works - `cy.get('[data-test="textarea"]').eq(1).should('be.visible')` OR `cy.get('[data-test="textarea"]').eq(1).should('exist')`.

Comment: Thats not going to work either, as Cypress would have already assessed the number of `textarea` before the second one has appeared. Is there a way to wait a certain amount of time for the condition to be true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can move the `eq()` into the selector with `:nth(1)`, which will cause the indexing to be part of the `cy.get()` retry mechanism

```js
cy.get('[data-test="textarea"]:nth(1)')
  .type('Hello').type('{enter}')
```

Or you can assert the length of the elements selected before indexing the list.

```js
cy.get('[data-test="textarea"]')
  .should('have.length', 2)
  .eq(1)
  .type('Hello').type('{enter}')
```

---

**Demo**

```
/// <reference types="@cypress/fiddle" />

const waitForAdd = {
  html: `
    <div id="parent">
      <textarea data-test="textarea">1</textarea>
      <button data-test="insert-item" onclick = "myFunction()"></button>
    </div>
    <script>
      const myFunction = () => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          const parent = document.querySelector('div#parent');
          let ta = document.createElement("textarea");
          ta.setAttribute('data-test', 'textarea');
          parent.appendChild(ta);
        }, 500)
      }
    </script>
  `,
  test: `
    cy.get('[data-test="insert-item"]').click();
    cy.get('[data-test="textarea"]:nth(1)')
      .type('Hello').type('{enter}')
    cy.get('[data-test="textarea"]:nth(1)')
      .invoke('val')
      .should('eq', 'Hello\\n')

    cy.get('[data-test="insert-item"]').click();
    cy.get('[data-test="textarea"]')
      .should('have.length', 3)
      .eq(2)
      .type('Hello again').type('{enter}')
    cy.get('[data-test="textarea"]')
      .eq(2)
      .invoke('val')
      .should('eq', 'Hello again\\n')
`
}
it('tests hello', () => {
  cy.runExample(waitForAdd)
})
```