# Cypress wait for table to load

Tags: vue.js, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm trying to test and click the table row that appears after I type text in the input component.
The table loads after delay (after getting response from external API). What woroked is using timeout that waits until certain element is loaded:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=searchBar]').type("Name")
cy.get('[data-cy=dataTable]').get('tbody').contains("td", "Result of name search",  {timeout: 15000}).click()
```

So cypress waits until there is such row with given value, but the value my change and wont always be the same so is there a way to do exatcly same thing as above but selecting second row after table loads? (by default there are no items in the table)

I tried using this:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=searchBar]').type("Name")
cy.get('[data-cy=dataTable]').get('tbody').get("tr").eq(2, {timeout: 15000}).click()
```

But it seems cypress loads the table after checking for the second `tr` which fails the test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Cypress - how to wait for second of two elements to appear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64943327/cypress-how-to-wait-for-second-of-two-elements-to-appear), you can add a `should()` to check the row length

```
cy.get('[data-cy=dataTable]')
  .find('tbody tr')              // ignore thead rows
  .should('have.length', 3)      // retries above cy.find() until true
  .eq(2)
  .click()
```

I'm not sure if you want to click the row (`tr`) or the cell (`td`). Looking at your first example (the one that works), it's the cell you want to click.

So you can add a cell selector

```
cy.get('[data-cy=dataTable]')
  .find('tbody tr')              // ignore thead rows
  .should('have.length', 3)      // retries above cy.find() until true
  .eq(2)                         // take 3rd row
  .find('td').eq(5)              // take 6th cell
  .click()
```

Answer (score 1):

Cypress requires parameter values to be in [quotation marks](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/get.html#Selector) also if you know exactly the text you will find I suggest the following approach that is working for me:

```
cy.get('[data-cy="searchBar"]').type("Name")
cy.contains('[data-cy="dataTable"] td', "Result of name search")
    .should('be.visible')
    .click()
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to make sure that cypress waits till the timeout, is to add the nth location of *tr* inside `cy.get()`, something like:

```
cy.get('[data-cy=dataTable] > tbody > tr:nth-child(3)', {timeout: 15000}).click()
```